# Loopback Making authenticated requests / access token management

Tags: angular, rest, ionic3, loopback

I was following the Loopback authentication documentation, all was clear and simple.
Creating user via POST, logging in via POST too.

But right after that I got stuck on how to get the access token and add it to the other requests.
In explorer side, you have just to copy/paste it in the token text-box and click set token.
How about API side? all through the documentation, the token is taken for granted and being initialized at each method beginning like:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN=6Nb2ti5QEXIoDBS5FQGWIz4poRFiBCMMYJbYXSGHWuulOuy0GTEuGx2VCEVvbpBK

# Authorization Header
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
http://localhost:3000/api/widgets

# Query Parameter
curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/widgets?access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN
```

or

```
var USER_ID = 1;
var ACCESS_TOKEN = '6Nb2ti5QEXIoDBS5FQGWIz4poRFiBCMMYJbYXSGHWuulOuy0GTEuGx2VCEVvbpBK';
// remove just the token
var token = new AccessToken({
  id: ACCESS_TOKEN
});
token.destroy();
// remove all user tokens
AccessToken.destroyAll({
  userId: USER_ID
});
```

how to implement my app where there are different users.

I am working on a Angular 6 app and an ionic 3 app.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I finished creating the mobile app and the web app, now I want to implement the authentication system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication in loopback is pretty transparent, which is great, it takes a few time to learn to master it.

You should look at ACL (access control), [doc here.](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Controlling-data-access.html)

This works with `Role`, ([doc here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html)), so basically, instead of managing all by yourself, you will tell loopback what type a user is (Role), and what that type of user can see and do within your app (ACL).

After that, when a request is made with an access token, loopback resolves the associated user and its role, then decides whether or not the action is permitted.

EDIT

To send a request, you add `access_token` as a query parameter: `http://domain/endpoint?access_token=*token*`. The token is acquired when the user logins in via the login endpoint, by the name of `id`

```
{
  "id": "LZQB7CmC7pYrk6vz7Ghf9MaIFRQYmnouKFxjolZE5GP6XqLal53fyLg475a8PTC8",
  "ttl": 1209600,
  "created": "2018-11-05T11:31:12.110Z",
  "userId": "5b8e7a47c6f12d00c5d6db29"
}
```

you can keep it in a local storage for later usage.

Comment: the last part is exactly what I don't understand. How to pass a request with the access token. Should I add a variable containing the token to the URI, or does loopback add it automatically after a login request was successful?

Comment: Sorry if I am a bit thick-headed, I already got there, my problem is how to get the token from the endpoint (POST response body) and let's say keep it in a local storage as you said. Here is a snippet of my code.
`return this.http.post(this.apiBaseURL + 'login', user).subscribe( response =>{
console.log(response)})`

Comment: Do you know the endpoint for login? You can find it in the api explorer for example `localhost:3000/explorer`

Comment: Yes actually the `apiBaseURL` I mentioned is `= http://localhost:3000/api/users/`

And the user is a JSON object with the credentials keys/values

Comment: Does your snippet work? The access token should be `response.id`

Comment: actually that snippet is a modification of another method I am using.
From the loopback explorer `localhost:3000/explorer`, I logged in so many times, and got the response body, including the access Token.
I am new here, I wanted to move this to chat but I couldn't, sorry

Comment: So did we make this work? Don't worry everyone was new here.

Comment: Thank you so much @Siyu, I was busy that's why I did not responde sooner.
As for this problem I followed your suggestion and used LocalStorage, it worked like a charm, although there is another solution, mentoned below

Answer (score 0):

For this particular project(this totally a personal choice), I wanted it to be a fully RESTful project, hence, no boot script and no static JavaScript definitions.
So, I had to toy a bit with loopback's predefined Models(User,Role,RoleMapping...)